# On my vote to close: Hand muscles for

Tags: discussion

[What everyday tasks can be adapted in a way that helps build muscles and technique for bouldering?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/what-everyday-tasks-can-be-tweaked-to-help-build-finger-and-hand-muscles-for-bou)

This appears to be not in any way substantially different from "[What hand and finger exercises help with climbing?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/547/what-hand-and-finger-exercises-help-with-climbing)"

The differences are trivial.  Muscles for bouldering and climbing are not substantially different.

Comment: Well I've just commented on the question before seeing this, otherwise Kevin's response says it well enough. Just to add though that the reason I specified bouldering was to avoid possible answers such as "carry a bit of rope and practise knots", or similar answers that would be irrelevant to me.

Comment: Thanks Peter!  For what it's worth I see your (and Kevin's) point.

Answer (score 4):

I understand your concern, but his question is slightly different. He asked what minor alterations he could make in his daily routine that would help. Most of the answers to my question require going out of one's way, some even to a gym if you don't happen to have dumbells, a chinup bar, or a campus board.  Proper answers to his question would not involve going (much) out of one's way, e.g. as he said, changing how one carries things. There will be some overlap, e.g. squeezing stress balls or grippers would apply to both, but there are limitations on what he is asking that are not in mine.

It is, of course, up to you to decide whether it is different enough.

Comment: Thanks for replying, good perspective on the differences.